# Open SQL Server Management Studio and Connect to Server from PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I want to launch SQL Server Management Studio using a PowerShell script. I know I could just launch the .exe to open it, but I also want to fill in the right server name and connect to it. The server name comes from parsing an XML file, which I already have the script configured to do. But I can't figure out how to pass it in and automatically connect to that server from a .ps1 file. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162825.aspx), the following should do it:

```
ssms.exe -S $serverName -E
```

I tested it on my laptop and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
start "filepath/ssms.exe"
```